# The number of positive integers of 5 digits such that each digit is 1, 2 or 3, and all three of the digits appear atleast once.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The number of positive integers of 5 digits such that each digit is 1, 2 or 3, and all three of the digits appear at least once.

Working:
Three 1, one 2, one 3, number of numbers = 5!/3! = 20 Two 1, one 2, two 3, number of numbers = 5!/(2!*2!) = 30 Two 1, two 2, one 3, number of such numbers = 5!/(2!*2!) = 30 One 1, one 2, three 3, number of such numbers = 5!/3! = 20 One 1, two 2, two 3, number of such numbers = 5!/(2!*2!) = 30 One 1, three 2, one 3, number of such numbers = 5!/(3!) = 20 Therefore, total number of such numbers = 20 + 30 + 30 + 20 + 30 + 20 = 150

Question: Is there any other possible easier, and simpler approach?

Comment: Stirling numbers: $3! \times {5\brace 3} = 150.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, Didn't quite get it, can you please elaborately explain the answer?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel , can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inclusion Exclusion is somewhat easier.

The total number of such integers, ignoring the requirement that all three digits appear, is $3^5$.  We then subtract off the instances in which one specified digit does not appear, that's $3\times 2^5$.  Then we add back the $3$ instances in which two specified digits do not appear.  Thus we get $$3^5-3\times 2^5+3=150$$

Comment: I have a confusion about what we're adding back at the end. $3^5$ includes the numbers:11111,22222,33333. $2^5$ includes 11111,22222,33333, but we're subtracting 3 times those 3 numbers. So wouldn't we add 6 back? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Take the number $11111$.  Of course that is in the original collection.  We want to remove it.  In the first step, we remove it too thoroughly...that is, we subtract it twice.  Once when we remove those integers without a $2$ and again when we remove those integers without a $3$.  To correct for our over-subtraction we have to add it back, once.

Comment: Perhaps it would clearer to think of the total count as: (Integers made from $1,2,3$)-(integers made from $1,2$)-(Integers made from $1,3$)-(Integers made from $2,3$)+(Integers made from $1$)+(Integers made from $2$)+(Integers made from $3$).

Comment: I got it now, thank you.